# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index::

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

**Here is my java code**

```
String insertSql = "CALL INSERT_EXAMPLE(?, ?, ?)";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(insertSql);
this.stmt.setObject(1, nameText);
this.stmt.setObject(2, phoneText);
this.stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
boolean results = stmt.execute();
Integer t_id = null;
if(results) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    if(rs.next()) {
         t_id = stmt.getInt("id");
    }
}
```

**Here is my procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_EXAMPLE(
    name                              IN                        VARCHAR2,
    phone                             IN                        VARCHAR2, 
    OUT_RESULT_CODE                   OUT                       INTEGER
    )
AS 
    id       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO USERS (
        T_NAME,
        T_PHONE
    ) VALUES (
        name,
        phone,
        ) RETURNING id INTO T_ID;
    COMMIT;
    OUT_RESULT_CODE := id;
END INSERT_EXAMPLE;
```

**Here is my sql**

> CREATE TABLE "DB_NAME"."USERS"(
> "T_ID" NUMBER,
> "T_NAME" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE),
> "T_PHONE" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE),
> CONSTRAINT "USERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("T_ID")
> USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
> STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
> PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
> BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
> TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
> ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
> PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
> NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
> STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
> PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
> BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
> TABLESPACE "TABLESPACE1" ;
> CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "DB_NAME"."USERS_ON_INSERT"
> BEFORE INSERT ON USERS
> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
> SELECT USERS_SEQ.NEXTVAL
> INTO :new.T_ID   FROM dual;
> END;
> /
> ALTER TRIGGER "DB_NAME"."USERS_ON_INSERT" ENABLE;

**Error:**

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
>
> and this line:  `boolean results = stmt.execute();`

Comment: Why `ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();`? The procedure does not generate a result set.

Comment: Are you sure that is the procedure you are calling? It shouldn't compile - `RETURNING id INTO T_ID` should be `RETURNING T_ID INTO id`, surely; or even skip the variable and use `RETURNING T_ID INTO OUT_RESULT_CODE`? And it has a stray comma. ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca6e7b6a9372d8adc384c0ac9a510718))

Comment: I thought I would get it when using the RETURNING @MT0

Comment: `this.stmt` and just `stmt` are not the same object in your code

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed it when I wrote it. Correct spelling indicates the same error. @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure has several errors:

1. Trailing comma after `phone` at the end of the `VALUES`.
2. `id` and `t_id` are the wrong way round in the `RETURNING` clause.

You can simplify the code to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_EXAMPLE(
    name            IN  USERS.T_NAME%TYPE,
    phone           IN  USERS.T_PHONE%TYPE,
    OUT_RESULT_CODE OUT USERS.T_ID%TYPE
)
AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO USERS (
    T_NAME,
    T_PHONE
  ) VALUES (
    name,
    phone
  ) RETURNING t_id INTO OUT_RESULT_CODE;
  
  COMMIT;
END INSERT_EXAMPLE;
/
```

Also, you should not have the `COMMIT` in the procedure as it will allow you to chain several procedure calls into the same transaction and then `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` them all together. If you `COMMIT` in the procedure and there is a subsequent error then you cannot `ROLLBACK` to the start of the transaction. Instead, you should either have the transaction set to auto-commit when it is closed or to explicitly commit before you close the connection.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0712242a526a4630fbd917acac870711)*

---

I can't test the Java code at the moment but I think it should be:

```java
String insertSql = "CALL INSERT_EXAMPLE(?, ?, ?)";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(insertSql);
stmt.setObject(1, nameText);
stmt.setObject(2, phoneText);
stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
boolean results = stmt.execute();
Integer t_id = null;
if(results) {
  t_id = stmt.getInt(3);
}
```

---

As an aside, you have defined the table with `"T_PHONE" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE)`; do you really expect a 400 byte string for a phone number?

Comment: The same mistake was made :((( this part `boolean results = stmt.execute();`